# Overriding the console in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I would like to modify the console object on the interpreter (v9.4.0) :

```
>console = {foo : 1, bar : 5}
{foo : 1, bar : 5}
```

Such a hacker! Now let's verify :

```
>console
Console {
  log: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  debug: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  info: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  dirxml: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  warn: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  error: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  dir: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  time: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  timeEnd: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  trace: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  assert: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  clear: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  count: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  countReset: [Function: bound countReset],
  group: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  groupCollapsed: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  groupEnd: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  Console: [Function: Console],
  table: [Function: table],
  markTimeline: [Function: markTimeline],
  profile: [Function: profile],
  profileEnd: [Function: profileEnd],
  timeline: [Function: timeline],
  timelineEnd: [Function: timelineEnd],
  timeStamp: [Function: timeStamp],
  context: [Function: context],
  [Symbol(counts)]: Map {} }
```

Why the reaffection is not taken in consideration? And if it's somehow a "forbidden action..." why node is not telling me so?...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its working in my terminal :)

Comment: monkey patching should work

Comment: Does it mean that from a node.js terminal to an other the same code would behave differently?

Comment: Usually it's a bad idea to extend globals and an even worse idea to override them, why don't you jut do something like `const log = (...args) => console.log('my own logger', ...args)` ?

Comment: Nino Filiu Agree with you. The point here was to mess with node.js CLI ;) Ifaruki Shubh monkey-patching works on v12.17.0 (but not on this version (v9.4.0) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is highly related with running your node within the CLI, whenever you execute a script that overrides the console, the console object will be overriden as expected. And I assume this is something to do in how they treat the [Global Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)

Different environment of execution return different things and this is just because of how the context is wrapping your code:

- Browser, it just works, you can try it out :D
- Repl: https://repl.it/repls/VioletredAstonishingTelephone, basically they create the script and then run it.
- CLI, your case, does not override it yet you can use Object.assign or modify the prototype to extend

So yes, the version matter because it affects the context in which your code gets executed (for node 12 it will work, for example)

http://www.joshuakehn.com/2011/10/20/Understanding-JavaScript-Context.html
Here you can read a bit more about why context cannot be overwritten, and since `console` is just a sugar coating for `this.console`, you wont be able to overwrite it with a reassignment (there is no setter function).

For more into the global: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global